# NPM build package after install

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, npm-scripts

I made a package with react and typescript. Because of how typescript handles the publishing of the classes and interfaces, I need to build the package and commit the built files with every change.
Is there a way to tell npm, that it has to build the specific package after `"npm install"` or `"yarn install"`?

I tried adding `"postinstall": "npm run build"` and `"prepare": "npm run build"` but it seems, that the project, in which the package is installed, runs this commands in his own root directory, so it builds itself, instead of just the package.

I thought of something like this:

1. Coding in a project
2. `yarn add packageX`
3. `yarn install`
4. packageX runs `npm run build` in its own directory
5. make changes in packageX
6. run `yarn update packageX`
7. packageX runs `npm run build` in its own directory
8. run `yarn build` in project root
9. Project builds itself

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Did you find a way to to this?